# Adding and Removing Event Handler in .net

Tags: c#, events, delegates

i recently created a sample application, wherein i implemented the events and delegates, when the Properties value is changed this event will raise, i have a question regarding events

1. Does event objects are created in memory? or they are just static object which gets removed once the event is fired?
2. Is it necessary to remove the handler once the event is executed, to free-up resources. does removing handler once done, boost's up the application performance, i am talking about the application which are using lots of events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events do take memory and are not garbage collected until after you unsubscribe from them.  They are a common cause of [memory leaks.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/05/05/memory-leak-via-event-handlers.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. Events can be both static and instance bound. Subscribers to the event are never removed while the event broadcaster is alive, unless implicitly done so, usually with the -= operator.
2. Yes, yes and yes. If you don't clean-up your subscribers you have a memory-leak waiting to happen.

If all this is a concern to you perhaps you could look into the [WeakEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`events` are like `delegates` ( with another layer of *protection*) .

when you register to an event - you are actually making a reference to another object.

this object *can't* go through GC because you made a reference to it !

it isnt "un-referenced".

but your object CAN go through GC. ( if un-referenced).

so you end up with memory leak.

you should *manually* remove the reference .